# Keep a copy of a bitbucket repo in githut with only tagged releases

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

The idea here is to keep using a BitBucket private git repo for internal development and have a "partial mirror" on GitHub in which to push only version-tagged releases (with no history between these releases).

I see more than one way to get to that but none that I really like.
Suggestions on the more elegant and less convoluted way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you make a tag in your local repo ('`repoB`': the one with the full history, pushed to BitBucket), you can add the content to a second local repo ('`repoG`'), which will then be pushed to GitHub.

```
cd /path/to/repoG
git --work-tree=/path/to/repoB add .
git commit -m "Add code as seen at tag x"
git push
```

That will work for *one* branch, but might be cumbersome if you had many branches.
At least, it won't record any intermediate history.

Comment: It took me a while (higher priority stuff coming in) but I finally managed to give it a try. Worked like a charm but the option is --work-tree, not --work-dir.